# Topology Continuous Functions Clarification

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

The question states:

Show that if $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, then the set $\{x \in \mathbb{R} :f(x) < \alpha\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ for each $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}.$

Unless there is a typo, I'm assuming I'm misunderstanding the question because $f(x) = \sin(x)$ is a continuous function where $f(x)$ is a closed set, $[-1,1]$, for any $\alpha > 1$ is a counterexample as far as I can tell.

If anyone could clarify what this question is asking me to prove, that would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that if $\alpha>1$ then

$$\{x\in\mathbb{R}: \sin x<\alpha\}=\mathbb{R}$$ which is an open set.

Note that $\{x\in\mathbb{R}: f(x)<\alpha\}=f^{-1}((-\infty, \alpha))$ is the preimage of the set $(-\infty, \alpha)$ by $f.$ Maybe you are thinking of the image instead of the preimage. And the image of an open set doesn't have to be open, being $f$ continous or not.

Comment: oh of course.  I was really overthinking this, thank you!